# Как посмотреть по http наличие файла? (node js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, веб-сервер

Как на ноде проверить наличие файла в дерриктории http? Мне не нужно его скачивать, просматривать, а просто знать - есть он или нет.
По сути мне нужно отправить http запрос например на  урл http://example.org/file.txt и получить ответ, распарсить и если 404 не наблюдаю то гуд иначе не гуд...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для определения наличия ресурса можно использовать метод **HEAD**. В ответ на HEAD запрос не будет возвращаться содержимое файла. При этом потребуется проверить код ответа: 200 - ресурс есть. Вы можете использовать, например, модуль **request**, который дочтаточно прост и содержит функцию head:

```
const request = require("request");

request.head("http://www.cfcl.com/vlb/Cuute/f/a-few-bricks.txt").on("response", res => {
    global.console.log(res.statusCode);
});
```

или использовать модуль **http** самой ноды и функцию **request**

```
const http = require("http");

const req = http.request(
    {
        hostname: "www.cfcl.com",
        path: "/vlb/Cuute/f/a-few-bricks.txt",
        method: "HEAD",
    },
    res => {
        global.console.log(res.statusCode);
    },
);

req.end();
```

Comment: большое спасибо, это должно работать =)